# Accessing variables from super blocks in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, inheritance, scope, jinja2

I have been trying to design a multi-section report document, with a primary template:

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% include "SectionA.html" %}
    {% include "SectionB.html" %}
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Where each of the included `SectionX.html` files extend a `base.html` file.

I would like to have `base.html` set a series of variables (used for control flow), which can be overridden in the `SectionX.html` files. I've tried to accomplish this with a `setVariables` block, but this does not work.

My `base.html` file looks something like:

```
{% block setVariables %}
{% set doFoo = False %}
{% set doBar = False %}
{% set bazValues = [] %}
{% endblock setVariables %}

{% if doFoo %}
...
```

and then override that section in each extension file:

```
{% block setVariables %}
{% set doFoo = sectionFoo %}
{% set doBar = sectionBar %}
{% set bazValues = sectionBaz %}
{% endblock setVariables %}
```

The problem is that, `doFoo` gets set in two completely separate scopes, and I am yet to find a way to access one from the other. I am unsure if there is a workaround using my current strategy, but I'd appreciate anything that might help in creating this modular, multi-section report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`include`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#include) tag instead to render the content of `base.html` in the current namespace.

So `base.html` should simply set default values for common variables:

```
{% set doFoo = False %}
{% set doBar = False %}
{% set bazValues = [] %}
```

and then in each individual HTML file:

```
{% include 'base.html' %}
```

Comment: That's a pretty decent solution, though it would be nice to have the ability to override blocks with `extend`. Any ideas? Or am I pretty much stuck with creating some elaborate control flow in the base file?

Comment: You can store the variables in a separate template file, such as `variables.jinja2`, dedicated for setting up variables for use with the `include` tag, while leaving `base.html` focused on defining the base HTML templates with `block` tags. Each individual HTML file will then include `variables.jinja2` and extend `base.html`.